# Mudando propriedades do webkit com jquery

Tags: jquery, css, webkit

Quero mudar uma propriedade do webkit usando jquery, tenho algo assim por enquanto.

```
$("#videoExe").css({
 '-webkit-media-controls-timeline': 'display="none"'
```

});

Mas não acontece nada...

Comment: Cara o que vc escreveu não faz muito sentido, vc não pode usar display:none para remover uma propriedade CSS. O correto seria algo como `'-webkit-media-controls-timeline': 'none'`

Comment: Onde está o seu player e o que você está querendo fazer?